# Problem I have space in listview between items (Container) with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Problem I have space in listview between items (Container) with flutter
Problem I have space in listview between items (Container) with flutter
[image]

this code :

```
 return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
    
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(

          children: [
            Container(

              width: width,
              height: 220,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/exclusion.png'),
                  // fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: width,
              height: 220,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/exclusion.png'),
                  // fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of the container you provided does not reflect the image height, so the image gets centered try to set `fit: BoxFit.fill` in the `DecorationImage` so that you see the actual height you need